# Noise Removal by Averaging Multiple Images in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, image-processing, bitmapdata

I tried code for two images but it fails after that limit..and not getting proper solution as well for collection of images you can visit
[Click Here For collection of images](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=bf4ec5c6de362e4c&id=BF4EC5C6DE362E4C%21105&authkey=%21AB4wND3PBOvqB6Y)

In these Images numbers on that images in green color are noise
please help me to find these solution

I have tried Following Code

```
    public Bitmap GetAveragedBitmap()
    {

        int numberOfImages = _imageCollection.Count;
        Bitmap bmpresult = null;


        if (numberOfImages > 1)
        {
            Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
            clock.Start();
            BitmapData[] bmpData = new BitmapData[numberOfImages];
            Bitmap[] bit = new Bitmap[numberOfImages];
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
            {
                bmpData[index] = _imageCollection[index].LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, _imageCollection[index].Width, _imageCollection[index].Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    if (bmpData[index].Width > width)
                    {
                        width = bmpData[index].Width;
                    }
                    if (bmpData[index].Height > height)
                    {
                        height = bmpData[index].Height;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    width = bmpData[0].Width;
                    height = bmpData[0].Height;
                }

                _imageCollection[index].UnlockBits(bmpData[index]);




            }//end of for loop
            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
            {
                bit[index] = new Bitmap(_imageCollection[index], width, height);

            }

            bmpresult = new Bitmap(width, height);
            BitmapData[] data = new BitmapData[numberOfImages];
            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
            {
                data[index] = bit[index].LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bit[index].Width, bit[index].Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            }
            data[1].Reserved = 1;
            BitmapData dataResult = bmpresult.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpresult.Width, bmpresult.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            unsafe
            {
                int[] remain = new int[numberOfImages];
                byte*[] ptr = new byte*[numberOfImages];
                long totalIntensity = 0;

                for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
                {
                    ptr[index] = (byte*)data[index].Scan0;
                    remain[index] = data[index].Stride - data[index].Width * 3;
                }
                byte* ptrResult = (byte*)dataResult.Scan0;
                //for resultant image
                int remainResult = dataResult.Stride - dataResult.Width * 3;


                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < width * 3; j++)
                    {
                        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
                        {
                            totalIntensity += (int)(ptr[index][0]);
                            ptr[index]++;
                        }
                    }
                    totalIntensity= totalIntensity/ numberOfImages;
                int average = (int)totalIntensity / (numberOfImages * height * width);
                //reset the pointer
                for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
                {
                    ptr[index] = (byte*)data[index].Scan0;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < width * 3; j++)
                    {

                        int result = 1;
                        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfImages; k++)
                        {

                            result = (ptr[k][0] * 1 * result);

                        }

                        ptrResult[0] = (byte)(result / average);

                        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
                        {
                            ptr[index]++;
                        }
                        ptrResult++;

                    }
                    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
                    {
                        ptr[index] += remain[index];
                    }

                    ptrResult += remainResult;


                }

                //  }//end of for loop                           

            }//end of unsafe

            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++)
            {
                bit[index].UnlockBits(data[index]);
            }
            bmpresult.UnlockBits(dataResult);
            clock.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine("Time for average " + clock.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        }
        return bmpresult;



    }
```

Comment: More details on what you have done please.

Comment: I have tried the following code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this,

I went for ideas to AForge framework and luckily there is filter [AForge.NET Framework Morph Class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/80514f4d-0a69-dacf-3a4e-8819250d8226.htm) that creates average from two images. I think the original intent was to morph two different images as an effect, but if you uses two shots of same scene you get noise reduction.

I would assume you would like 2-n averaging so I suggest you take the source of the Merge filter as a starting point and create your customized version for multiple images.

Here is source : [GitHub.com | AForge.NET / Merge.cs](https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET/blob/a299890d7916ef301d620bed4c282bb9173278fa/Sources/Imaging/Filters/2%20Source%20filters/Morph.cs)

PS. You might need to downloaded whole AForge project source to find where to put your implementation better.